# ggplot - Conditional background

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to conditionally color the background when the differences between the subjects are lower than 10.

For example:
[image]

Sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(895)
df <- data.frame(s1 = rnorm(20, 85, 3), 
                 s2 = rnorm(20, 75, 3)) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("Time") %>% 
  mutate(Time = as.numeric(Time), 
         dif = abs(s1 - s2) < 10)
```

For now, the solution that I found was to color the background using `geom_tile`. However, I wasn't able to remove the tiles' borders:

```
df %>% 
  gather(subject, value, -Time, -dif) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Time, value, 
             group = subject, 
             color = subject)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x=Time,y=80, height = 20, 
                color = "NA", fill=dif)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `col="NA"` outside the aesthetic.

```
geom_tile(aes(x=Time,y=80, height = 20, fill=dif), col = "NA")
```

Or even better... If you don't want all of your graph components to use the same aesthetic (say colour), then don't put them in the top-level ggplot function - put them in the separate geom_ functions to follow.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  gather(subject, value, -Time, -dif) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Time, value)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x=Time, y=80, height = 25, fill=dif), alpha=0.5) + 
  geom_line(aes(col = subject), lwd=1)
```

[image]

You may also want to change the colours of the tile or lines so that they don't obscure each other. Here I've used transparency (alpha=0.5) to make the tiles less transparent so the lines are visible.